# Python import functions from module twice with different internal imports

Tags: python, python-import

I have a module `lib` that needs `numpy`. So, for instance, let's say I have a hypothetical function that looks like

```
import numpy
def doSomething(x):
    return numpy.sqrt(x)
```

Now to use that function in a separate module, I will import the name as

```
from lib import doSomething
...
```

Here is the tricky part... Now I want to expose another version of `doSomething` for which `numpy` has been imported from another library (in particular, from `autograd`). So, for instance, I would like to be able to have a function

```
from autograd import numpy
def doSomething(x):
    return numpy.sqrt(x)
```

where the only difference between these functions is where `numpy` is being imported from. In particular, I would like to use both versions of `doSomething` in the same code, that is, I would like some way of importing `doSomething` twice... once with the default `numpy`, and once with the `numpy` from autograd. Something like this:

```
useAutograd = False
from lib(useAutograd) import doSomething
useAutograd = True
from lib(useAutograd) import doSomething as doSomethingAutograd
```

There are a couple options here that I know of, but none which are satisfactory.

1. I would make a copy of the codebase, and have one that uses the default `numpy`, and one which uses `numpy` from `autograd`. This is bad because it would require me to maintain two codebases which are copies of each other, only with different imports.
2. I could put in a conditional import:

   ```
   try:
       from autograd import numpy
   except ImportError:
       import numpy
   ```

   This is bad because the user has no control over which version is imported... If they have autograd, then they must use that version.
3. I could define an environmental variable to control the import

   ```
   import os
   if os.environ.get('AUTOGRADNUMPY'):
       try:
           from autograd import numpy
       except ImportError:
           import numpy
   else:
       import numpy
   ```

   This has the downside that although the user can control the import, they can only pick one version (as far as I know). So they could not use both versions in the same code.

Are there any better alternatives for this use case?

Background for those interested:

`Autograd` has its own set of functions which mimic `numpy` and allow one to easily compute derivatives using automatic differentation (in the same vein as tensorflow), without requiring expensive numerical differentiation.

HOWEVER, their numpy implementation is not the most optimized version (AFAIK). So it would be advantageous to allow the user to use the version with the `autograd` import when they will need the jacobian of the function, and to use their default, highly optimized numpy package when they don't.

Comment: This is an interesting problem but still, why would you want to do such a thing?

Comment: Do you have a problem with the implementation that you showed us? I'm not sure I understand what you want to do and obtain

Comment: I will update the question with the rationale...

Comment: So if I understand well.. OK, I cannot understand what you mean. If you just want to import two different `doSomething`, what's wrong with it? You won't import multiple `numpy` as `numpy` imported from `autograd` is also pointed to which imported by `import numpy`. They are the same.

Comment: Would it work at all, as long as the numpy module is called `numpy` in both cases? How will they be stored in `locals()`? Can you try importing them as separate entites simply using `import numpy as numpy` and then `from autograd import numpy as anp`. The put the conditions, try/except as required in your function? I hope I have not misunderstood something!

Comment: Not sure I understand... Could you make an answer?

Comment: @bremen_matt I am still not convinced of the need of such a thing.

Comment: `from autograd import numpy` gives what advantages that `import numpy` cannot give?

Comment: `from autograd import numpy` is not actually importing the default `numpy` AFAIK. It is a subset of `numpy` functions which they wrote to mimic `numpy`, but which are optimized for automatic differentation, but perhaps not for speed

Comment: I've seen some projects have similar problems. I think adding a flag in `doSomething` to determine which `numpy` to use is good enough. You can set a default value, and manually set it only if you want to use another version of `numpy`.

Comment: The problem is that I have thousands of small functions. Adding a flag to each one seems a bit ridiculous here. I mean what happens if another package comes along with a different version? Then I have to add another line there? I could do it, but it seems far from elegant.

Comment: Right now, donkopotamus seems to have the best solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your desire is to avoid duplicating your code base, make your interface a class instead.  For example:

```
class using_numpy:
    import numpy

    @classmethod
    def do_something(cls, x):
        return cls.numpy.sqrt(x)

class using_autograd(using_numpy):
    from autograd import numpy
```

Now `using_numpy.do_something` will use `numpy`, and `using_autograd.do_something` will use `autograd.numpy`.

Alternatively, if you are uncomfortable with `classmethod`, you could make your interfaces instances of a class, for example:

```
class interface:
    def __init__(self, mdl):
        self.mdl = mdl

    def do_something(self, x):
        return self.mdl.sqrt(x)

import numpy
import autograd

with_numpy = interface(numpy)
with_autograd = interface(autograd.numpy)
```

Comment: Hmm interesting. I didn't think of this. This looks really good

Comment: Alternative 2 has been enlightening.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything to achieve this.

If you do

```
from lib import doSomething
from lib_with_autograd import doSomething as doSomethingAutograd
```

each of those functions uses the `numpy` imported in their specific module. So `doSomethingAutograd` uses the one imported in `lib_with_autograd` and `doSomething` uses the one imported in `lib`

Comment: Yes, but as I say, this requires that I copy the entire codebase from `lib` into a new codebase where the only difference is the import statements. Thus I would have to start maintaining 2 libraries

Comment: @bremen_matt But you only need to do it for those functions for which you would want to use `autograd`. All the other ones you can import from the normal `lib`.

Comment: Essentially every function (of which there are thousands) is using numpy internally. There are almost no functions that do not use numpy.

Answer (score 1):

Since everything in python is an object, including modules, you can do something like:

```
def doSomething(x, numpy=None):
    if numpy is None:
        import numpy
    return numpy.sqrt(x)
```

Then you can call the function without setting `numpy`, then it will use the default numpy. If you want to use another numpy, just call it as such:

```
from autograd import numpy as autograd_numpy
doSomething(x, numpy=autograd_numpy)
```

Comment: This would work and is similar to the version proposed by donkopotamus. However, I believe his suggestion is slightly better because it more naturally handles subfunctions in the package. With this approach, if one method called another, then you would have to be sure to pass the module to the subfunctions. With the other approach, that would be much less error prone.